# image button opening another url

Tags: html, hyperlink, imagebutton, openurl

I'm working on a project where I want to have an image as a button, and when pressed it should open another URL.

I've managed to open another URL with just plain text by using this:

```
<a href="test.html">Page2</a>
```

I've tried these 2 ways:

This one doesn't do anything from my understanding:

```
<a href="index.html" src="btn.png"></a>
```

This one does show the image / button but does not open the next URL when pressed.

```
<input type="image" src="btn.png" a href="index2.html"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="btn.png" alt="Index"/></a>
```

Have a look here:

http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/conclusion/